# I can't use the packages that come with anaconda with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, package

```
conda list
```

lists everything.

[image]

pycharm is using the conda virtual environment.
[image]

why isn't any of the packages listed?

Comment: I don't use pycharm but it looks like your project has set up its own environment rather than using the default anaconda one. At a guess, there'll be a way to import packages from a more general environment (anaconda's base/root environment) and add them to the one specific to your project

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve the issue(for Ubuntu 16.04) by:-

1. By going to File > Settings > Project: Name of your project(drop-down menu) > Project Interpreter > Clicking on the gear icon from the right side of the panel > Add Local > From left side of the panel select Conda Environment > From right side of the panel select Existing Environment, now paste the path of your Python Interpreter where it is asked. You can get this path using the command `which python`. Make sure that you tick on the checkbox 'Make available to all projects', so, that you won't have to repeat the process for every project.
2. Now restart Pycharm and you will be good to go.

Comment: This worked for me. There were 2 conda interpreters. I selected the one that included the libraries I need.

Comment: Jetbrains needs to realize that some of their users install conda per user and not globally on Windows

Answer (score 3):

As `roganjosh` mentioned, it looks like the `conda list` in your `bash` terminal is showing all the packages in your root environment whereas PyCharm is using an environment entitled `untitled`. It sounds like you want to be using your root environment in PyCharm. If that is the case then you need to change your interpreter.

Probably the simplest way to do that is to do `which python` in your terminal, where you are seeing all those packages, and then select that `python` path in PyCharm by (1) clicking the gear icon in the upper right hand corner of your screenshot (2) choose "Add Local" (3) paste in that python path.

Comment: @EmmaNej : come out of python terminal and tye again.